# How can I make unitest to find my single test method only once?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a python unitest script with an double inheritance of the `TestCase` as follows:

```
import unittest
class Upper(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dummy(self):
        pass

class Lower(Upper):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

The idea is to define an upper class with a test method implementation, and derive from this class (in different subdirectories) which contain some additional setup functionality. In the end, there is one `upper.py` from which many different `test_lower.py` are derived. The test methods are ONLY implemented in `upper.py`.

Given the example above now I do a  `python test_example.py` only to see that python is trying to run 2 tests! The script contains exactly one test, so why is unittest executing two tests?

I assume that unittest finds one test within `Lower` and one test in `Upper` somehow, but I only want to execute the test which is found in `Lower` (because of additional and required setup functionalities). How can I achieve this?

**Context** In the real case the two classes are defined in two different files, residing in two directories. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unittest library iterates over a TestCase subclass attributes, finding methods which start with `test_`. In case of `Lower` test case it inherits a method from its parent, so it is executed twice - once inside `Upper` test case and second time inside `Lower` class.
If both of the test cases are meant to be run, the only solution i see is to make a take out `test_dummy` test to an other subclass of `Upper`

If you want a test to be run in a parent class, but skipped in some of its subclasses, try this:

```
import unittest
class Upper(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_dummy(self):
        pass

class Lower(Upper):
    def test_dummy(self):
        return  # skip test

    @unittest.skip  # or this - but ugly
    def test_dummy(self):
        return  # skip test

if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

UPDATE:

I think now i understand what you want: you want the test method to be run only in subclasses. Then i suggest you to inherit `Upper` from `object`, and the subclasses - both  from `Upper` and `TestCase`:

```
import unittest

class Upper(object):

    def test_dummy(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

class Lower(unittest.TestCase, Upper):

    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running:

```
python test2.py -v
test_dummy (__main__.Lower) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: I do not quite understand what you are suggesting. The test method HAS to reside in `Upper`, that is the whole point of the idea. I do not want to copy-and-pase the exact same test method code into several dubdirectories.

Comment: If the skip works, I am shown one test running and one skipped. This is not acceptable, as I need to run all test, without having skipped tests.

Comment: Good idea, but I need functionalities of `unittest` INSIDE the class in `upper`. (In fact, I am not using `unittest` directly, but a different derived class, and require to use functions inside).

Comment: If you could show how and where to use `self.assert` exactly, and how `Lower` and `Upper` has to look like this might be useful.